# List.Any get matched String

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

```
FilePrefixList.Any(s => FileName.StartsWith(s))
```

Can I get `s` value here? I want to display the matched string.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`Any` determines only  if  there is a match, it doesn't return anything apart from the `bool` and it needs to execute the query.

You can use `Where` or `First`/`FirstOrDefault`:

```
string firstMastch = FilePrefixList.FirstOrDefault(s => FileName.StartsWith(s)); // null if no match

var allMatches = FilePrefixList.Where(s => FileName.StartsWith(s));
string firstMastch = allMatches.FirstOrDefault(); // null if no match
```

So `Any` is fine if all you need to know is if ther's a match, otherwise you can use `FirstOrDefault` to get the first match or `null`(in case of reference types).

Since `Any` needs to execute the query this is less efficient:

```
string firstMatch = null;
if(FilePrefixList.Any(s => FileName.StartsWith(s)))
{
    // second execution
    firstMatch = FilePrefixList.First(s => FileName.StartsWith(s));
}
```

If you want to put all matches into a separate collection like a `List<string>`:

```
List<string> matchList = allMatches.ToList(); // or ToArray()
```

If you want to output all matches you can use `String.Join`:

```
string matchingFiles = String.Join(",", allMatches);
```

Comment: There's also Single() if you want to ensure there's only one match.

Answer (score 15):

Not with `Any`, no... that's *only* meant to determine whether there are any matches, which is why it returns `bool`. However, you can use [`FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault) with a predicate instead:

```
var match = FilePrefixList.FirstOrDefault(s => FileName.StartsWith(s));
if (match != null)
{
    // Display the match
}
else
{
    // Nothing matched
}
```

If you want to find *all* the matches, use `Where` instead.

Answer (score 3):

if `FilePrefixList` is a `List<string>`, you can use `List<T>.Find` method:

```
string first = FilePrefixList.Find(s => FileName.StartsWith(s));
```

fiddle: [List.Find vs LINQ](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CTgjtd) (Find is faster)

> `List<T>.Find` [(MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc(v=vs.110).aspx) returns the first element that matches the conditions defined by the specified predicate, if found; otherwise, the default value for type T

Answer (score 2):

`Enumerable.Any()` returns `bool` denoting whether *any* item matched the criteria.

If you need the matched item, use `SingleOrDefault()` instead:

```
var matchedPrefix = FilePrefixList.SingleOrDefault(s => FileName.StartsWith(s));
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342451(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Please note, that SingleOrDefault will throw an exception if there is more than one result.

Comment: @Serv, Yes but since the list is supposed to contain file prefixes, I assume there would be no duplicates.

Comment: I didn't even parse that information. Could very well be.

Comment: @haim770: but also note that `Single` is less efficient than `First`. It needs to check if there's a second match which either throws an exception or checks every item of the whole sequence. Can make a major difference in Linq-To-Objects.

Answer (score 2):

please check try this:
we assuming FilePrefixList is collectionlist

```
 class A
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

 List<A> FilePrefixList= new  List<A>();
             FilePrefixList.Add(new A
            {
                ID = 1,
                Name = "One"
            });
            FilePrefixList.Add(new A
            {
                ID =2,
                Name = "Two"
            });
            FilePrefixList.Add(new A
            {
                ID = 3,
                Name = "Three"
            });
```

select data from list is:

```
var listItems = FilePrefixList.Where(x =>x.Name.StartsWith("T")).ToList();
```